# NodeJS: How is the value for process.env.PORT assigned?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run my NodeJS app the `process.env.PORT` is `undefined`. I am noticing this when I try to log the value:

`console.log(process.env.PORT) // undefined`

My question is, how to I change that environment object value? Thanks for an answer!

Comment: You have not set it in your environment before rinng your app? To set it do like this ”PORT=NUM node SCRIPT”. You could also set it using a ”.env” file if you are using ”dotenv” package. There are many other ways.

Comment: It's an *environment* variable. You will need to contact the documentation of your operating system - this has nothing to do with node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `process.env.PORT` variable returns the value of the `PORT` environment variable.

If for example `app.js` is your apps entry point, then accessing `process.env.PORT` from within your app would yield a value of `8080` if you were to run this on the terminal:

```
PORT=8080 node app.js
```

#### Update

To specify the `PORT` environment variable when running your app on Heroku, login to your Heroku account, select your application from the list, click the "settings" tab and then click "Reveal Config Vars". Enter a `PORT` key with the required port value, and click the "Add" button.

[image: Set env config for heroku app]

Comment: I'm uploading it to heroku and was wondering how is the value assigned to it. It is done somehow the same way I type it into terminal?

Comment: Thanks :) It helped a lot. So some parts of process.env are not known at the time of writing the code, am I right?

Comment: You're welcome, that's correct - `process.env` is dynamic based on the environment variables specified at runtime

Answer (score 1):

For getting your process.env.PORT you need to defined PORT varable in .env file defined at root level of project.
Then, you need to use dotenv npm package for loading process.env variables in your project.
For details about dotenv you can refer to following documentation:

https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme

Comment: You don’t have to use a ”.env” file? You can set it directly in either package.json or from the terminal when starting your application.

Comment: yes you can add them in terminal but for large applications we generally specify all env  variables in .env file.

Comment: What I am saying is that there are many ways of doung this. Reading your answear it sounds like this is the only approach :)